# Only using a Map or mapping file with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I'm essentially trying to convert XML to SQL. My goal is to have a default schema and mapping of attributes to columns, but to have it be fully user editable so future XML changes don't require the user editing code and recompiling.

This means however that I can't use normal POJOs because if a new attribute is added in the XML there isn't a matching POJO field for hibernate to use. However I'm really trying to use Hibernate or something similar so I don't have to worry about database specific SQL.

How would I use Hibernate as basically a DDL engine using maybe a basic Map or even the full mapping file, but no POJOs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use 'dynamice-map' as entity mode. See [Dynamic models](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/persistent-classes.html#persistent-classes-dynamicmodels). We have used this in one of our projects, You will loose the comfort of static typing. You can not tell which fields are present in a entity by just looking at the code.